# create-react-app require all files in dir

Tags: reactjs, webpack, markdown, github-pages, create-react-app

I want to build a blog with create-react-app and host it on Github pages.
I want the posts content to be md files I dump on some folder in the repo.

I'm able to render md files currently only by requiring each file in code, fetching it and rendering.
this s not very scalable.. I don't want to have an import line for every file I add...

Is there a way for me to "require" all of the files in a specific folder so I can fetch them in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout gatsby https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby

You should be able to get an idea how they are pulling this off without a backend service. Gatsby does exactly what you're describing. If anything you should be able to extract the functionality if you don't want to go with the whole framework. It is very very fast though =)

Comment: I'll check it out. might be complicated to understand since I'm not a very experienced FED but I'll try